# Cancel libcurl easy handle

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, curl, libcurl

Is there an easy way to cancel a curl_easy_perform from another thread?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use the callback functions (write/read/progress) to perform the cancel.  The other thread needs to set a flag and the callback function checks the flag and returns the proper value to cancel the operation.

Comment: When I return from curl_progress_callback non-zero value, it stop sending request, bit also program is crashed. Is it mention to be? Can you advise method for cancelling without crashing?