# How can I immediately cancel a curl operation?

Tags: c++, multithreading, curl, boost-thread

I'm using [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) in C++, and I'm calling `curl_easy_perform` in a separate thread from my UI using [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/thread.html).

The main UI has a cancel button that I'd like to be perfectly responsive (i.e., when a user clicks on it, it should immediately react). I have read, write, and progress callbacks set up to read an atomic `should_cancel` variable (as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235763/cancel-libcurl-easy-handle) question), but there are two problems:

1. There's often a very small (but noticeable) delay from when cancel is pressed to when the curl operation completes.
2. Occasionally, there's a very long (sometimes interminable) delay. In this case, either:

   a. the progress, read, and write callbacks simply aren't called for a long time, or

   b. the progress callback *is* called, I return a nonzero value (meaning it should terminate), but the curl operation doesn't complete for a while longer (in fact, the progress function is called again in the meantime!)

So:

1. Why do the long delays happen (especially without calling the progress function)?
2. What should I do instead to allow the cancel button to react properly?

One possibility is to tell the UI that the cancel operation succeeded, but keep running the curl thread in the background until it cancels. The problem with this (I think) is that it forces the `should_cancel` variable to be global, instead of scoped to the dialog box where the operation began.

Comment: How about using the non-blocking curl_multi_perform?http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_perform.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your basic idea is right. You should detach the curl operation from the UI. However, the implementation should be changed a bit. You shouldn't be using a global `should_cancel`. Instead, you should have a global `current_request` pointer, to an object of type `Request`. This type should have an internal `cancel` flag, and a public `Cancel()` function. In response to the cancel button, you call `Cancel` on the `current_request` and then null it. A cancelled request is then repsonsible for its own cleanup at a later time (it's a thread, after all).

You'll need to be careful with your mutexes to prevent zombie objects. There's an inherent race condition between a cancel and a request completion.

Comment: wait, what? No.. he should use the curl multi API. And use a global atomic boolean for example to stop the (while) loop in the thread. Instead of calling `curl_easy_perform` he/she should use the following functions: `curl_multi_perform`, `curl_multi_poll` and `curl_multi_cleanup`. This allows you to stop the request at any given time.

Answer (score 16):

I met the same problem with curl 7.21.6. When tring to abort smtp protocol.
Returning CURL_READFUNC_ABORT from read callback stops the transfer but curl_easy_perform does not return for next 5+ minutes. Probably it waits for tcp timeout.

To walk it around i store socket used by curl (replace curl_opensocket_callback), and close this socket directly when needed.

```
curl_socket_t storeCurlSocket(SOCKET *data, curlsocktype purpose, struct curl_sockaddr *addr) {
    SOCKET sock = socket(addr->family, addr->socktype, addr->protocol);
    *data = sock;
    return sock;
}

size_t abort_payload(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, SOCKET *curl_socket) {
    SOCKET l_socket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    swap(l_socket, *curl_socket);
    if (l_socket != INVALID_SOCKET) {
        shutdown(l_socket, SD_BOTH);
        closesocket(l_socket);
    }
    return CURL_READFUNC_ABORT;
}

...calling perform...
        SOCKET curlSocket;
        curet = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION, storeCurlSocket);
        curet = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETDATA, &curlSocket);
        curet = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, abort_payload);
        curet = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, &curlSocket);
        curet = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (curet == CURLE_ABORTED_BY_CALLBACK) {
          //expected abort
        }
...
```

Comment: Probably hacking in and closing the socket manually is the best option for REALLY immediate connection interrupt, bonus points for thread-safety of that operation. (never try `curl_easy_cleanup` on a thing that may be actively curl_easy_/perform/recv/send/'ed by another thread.. but with socket it's fine and curl doesnt crash!). You may be interested in the fact that currently curl makes the socket easily available with `curl_socket_t sockfd; curl_easy_getinfo(handle, CURLINFO_ACTIVESOCKET, &sockfd);` so you can obtain it anytime you have access to the curl handle.

Answer (score 1):

The delay could happens because `curl_easy_perform` is busy with the write or read callback, try to return 0 from the write callback or `CURL_READFUNC_ABORT` from the read callback.  According with the documentation, if the value returned by the write callback differs from the value received by the function the transfer will be aborted, and if the read callback return `CURL_READFUNC_ABORT`, the transfer will be aborted too (valid from version 7.12.1 of the library).

Comment: I am! I'm passing the "cancel" return code to all three callbacks (read, write, and progress), but none of the callbacks are called in the first "long delay" case.

Comment: I think you should rewrite your thread code. Do not use `curl_easy_perform`, instead use the curl multi API. Like: `curl_multi_perform`, `curl_multi_poll` and `curl_multi_cleanup`.